# Write before paste table in Outlook - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using the following code to paste a table in a new email on Outlook:

```
'Copy range of interest
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("B2:D5")
r.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Get its Word editor
outMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'To paste as picture
wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

'To paste as a table
'wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
```

But I need to write a message before the pasted table.
I already tried to use the parameters:

```
With OutMail
    .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .HTMLBody = "This is an e-mail"
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the e-mail message.
    .Display
End With
```

But when paste the table it overwrites the .HTMLBody parameter.

Bellow the entire code that I'm using:

```
Sub btn_Copiar_Clique()

'Range("B2:L44").Select

Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A2:L44")
r.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Get its Word editor
outMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor


'To paste as picture
'wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture


   With outMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Relatório de Captação de Fundos - Private"
            .HTMLBody = "Boa tarde," & "<br>" & "Segue relatório de captação dos fundos vendidos no private." & "<br>"

            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display   'or use .Display
            '.Send
    End With

'To paste as a table
wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False

End Sub
```

Look that the `wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False` is after the parameter `.HTMLBody`. That makes the pasting code overwrite the parameter `.HTMLBody`.

I'm using these libraries:
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library *This is needed
Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library *This is needed

Comment: I put the entire code that i'm using.

Comment: Good, I'll put that I'm using Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library and Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've put the backtick but mine is like that ' and the one that is aceptable is that ` so I needed to copy your and paste into the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a paste, to add above an existing .HTMLBody:

```
.HTMLBody = "text" & .HTMLBody
```

Answer (score 0):

*You're already using `.Display` so no need for second one, keep the following*

> ```
> 'Get its Word editor
> outMail.Display
> Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
> Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
> ```

---

*After you add the **`HTMLBody`** use **[InsertParagraphAfter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212291(v=office.11).aspx)** Example*

> ```
> With outMail
>     .To = ""
>     .cc = ""
>     .BCC = ""
>     .Subject = "Relatório de Captação de Fundos - Private"
>     .HTMLBody = "Boa tarde," & "<br>" & "Segue fundos vendidos no private."
>
>      wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
>      wordDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
> End With
> ```

*To add something after see example*

> ```
>      wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
>      wordDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
>      wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
>      wordDoc.Range.InsertAfter "bla bla"
> ```

Comment: It worked but how I write something after `wordDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture` ?

Answer (score -1):

Use worddoc.paragraph(3) in the line after "bla bla".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).