# Copy range of cells from Excel as picture and add text in the email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm tying to add range of cells as a picture from the active workbook along with some text.

But for some reason it skipping the text and only pasting the image in the email body.

How do I  fix this?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub POSTRUN()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim Olobj As Outlook.Application
Set Olobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim subject As String
    subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SendMail").Range("I5").Text
    Debug.Print subject



Dim i As Long
Dim Filter As String
    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                       Chr(34) & " >= '01/01/1900' And " & _
                       Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                       Chr(34) & " < '12/31/2100' And " & _
                       Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                       Chr(34) & "Like '%" & subject & "%'"

Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False

For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    DoEvents
    If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
        Dim Item As Object
        Set Item = Items(i)
        Debug.Print Item.subject ' Print on Immediate Window
        Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime ' Print on Immediate Window

        Dim r As Range
        Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("post").Range("A1:M30")
        r.Copy

        Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set outMail = Olobj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
         Dim body


        Dim ReplyAll As Outlook.MailItem
        Set ReplyAll = Item.ReplyAll
         Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
        Set wordDoc = ReplyAll.GetInspector.WordEditor

        With ReplyAll


             .HTMLBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
              "Hi  <br><br>" & _
              "The " & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
                      InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & _
              "</B> has been posted.<br>" & _
              .HTMLBody

              wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

             .Display
            Exit For

        End With

      End If
      Next

      End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write before paste table in Outlook - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514116/write-before-paste-table-in-outlook-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Its not skipping, you are simply overriding the `HTMLBody` with the image your pasting, so what you need to do is work with [Paragraphs Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/paragraphs-object-word)*

*Example*

```
With ReplyAll
    .HTMLBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
                "Hi  <br><br>" & _
                "The " & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
                         InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & _
                "</B> has been posted.<br>" & .HTMLBody

    .Display

     With wordDoc.Paragraphs(2)
        .Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        .Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        .Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceDouble
     End With
    Exit For
End With
```

*Also remove following code*

> ```
> Dim Olobj As Outlook.Application
> Set Olobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
> Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
> Set outMail = Olobj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
> Dim body
> ```

*You already have it*

> ```
> Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
> Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
> Dim Item As Object
> Set Item = Items(i)
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, because of you i learnt so much.. and thanks to the stackoverflow for creating such a platform like this.