# Paste text and multiple Excel ranges as images in Outlook using wordeditor

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to paste multiple Excel ranges as images in Outlook mail using VBA. I am using the answer to this question ([Pasting an Excel range into an email as a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092999/pasting-an-excel-range-into-an-email-as-a-picture)) to paste a range of excel as image in mail but as soon as I paste another  range, it overwrites the previous image. Is there anyway to change the cursor position in Outlook mail using wordeditor. I tried using collapse before pasting the image but it did not help. Also how do I add the text to it as using Outmail.body to edit anything gets overwritten too by the image pasted afterwards. 
 This is the code I am using:

```
Sub Sendmail()
Dim r as range
Set r = Range("C2:O13)
r.copy
dim outlookapp as Outlook.Application
set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
dim outMail As Outlook.Mailitem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With outMail
.Display
.CC = "xyz@abc.com"
.Subject = "Test"
.Body = "Dear" & "Macro" & vbnewline
end with
outmail.Display
'Opening wordeditor
dim worddoc as Word.Document
Set worddoc = Outmail.GetInspector.WordEditor
worddoc.range.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture
'Adding new line after pasting image
worddoc.range.Insertafter vbNewline
' Adding second image
dim s as range
set s= Range(P2:Z30)
s.copy
worddoc.range.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture
```

Comment: whats your code?

Comment: WordEditor the [add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/p/wordeditor/9wzdncrdgbpk) or WordEditor the [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor)? Can you add to specific detail about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far?  (see [ask] as well as [mcve]).

Comment: Sorry for not adding Code before. I have added the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the below code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
    Set rng = Sht.Range("B4:L17")
        rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With Email
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

         wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture

'        if need setup inlineshapes hight & width
         With wdDoc
            .InlineShapes(1).Height = 130
         End With

        .Display
    End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

For more information, please refer to these links:

[Copy Excel range as Picture to Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896499/copy-excel-range-as-picture-to-outlook)

[Copy range of cells from Excel as picture and add text in the email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682060/copy-range-of-cells-from-excel-as-picture-and-add-text-in-the-email-body)