# Insert a screenshot after an email introduction

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the code below which is basically taken a screenshot of an userform and paste it in an outlook application. The macro is working fine.

What I am trying to achieve is to put an email introduction and then after paste the screenshot, but I am not able to do it properly because the screenshot is not being put after the text.

This is my code

```
Sub Screenshotemail()

    Dim doc                   As Object, rng As Range

    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
    DoEvents

    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
         Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
         doc.Range(0, 0).Paste
        .display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Body = "Dear All, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "I kindly remind you that forecasts for program " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
         & "Please enter your forecast at the link below." _
         & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & lien & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Best Regards,"
        .Subject = "Test:"
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
    End With

End Sub
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend, It take me a few hours but i guess it works

just use, htmlbody instead body, and concat the htmlbody after your messagge

reference
[Write before paste table in Outlook - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514116/write-before-paste-table-in-outlook-excel-vba)

Sub Screenshotemail()

```
Dim doc As Object, rng As Range
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdRange As Range

Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
DoEvents
Set wdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'ActiveSheet.Paste
With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    doc.Range(0, 0).Paste
    .display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .htmlbody = "Dear All, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "I kindly remind you that forecasts for program " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
     & "Please enter your forecast at the link below." _
     & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & lien & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Best Regards," & .htmlbody
    .Subject = "Test:"
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: If you replace Chr(10) with "<p>" the text may look better.

Comment: @Miguel Angel Cortez Rodriguez =. Thanks a lot for your help. It was exactly what I was had in mind. Muchas gracias mi amigo. Saludos de Brazil..

Comment: @niton.. Thanks for your idea. I was able to use it as well..